# PhantomJS 32767 pixel width limitation

Tags: phantomjs

I found a limitation on PhantomJS, it can't render a page with a width of more than 32768 pixels

```
 <div style="border-style: solid; float: left; 
             border-color: blue; border-width: 2; 
             width: 40000px; height: 100px">
    great
</div>
```

Is there any settings so PhantomJS can render page with a width of more than 32k pixels?